# Force of water hitting a wall

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, fluid-dynamics, pressure, water

If you had a 8" pipe with 500psi stream of water exiting it and hitting a wall at 90 degrees 8 feet away, what would the force of the water on the wall be?
Thank you all.
Non-mathematician.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Flow at wall.]

Using [Bernoulli's equation](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/pber.html) and the momentum conservation equation, we can show that water flowing out of a pipe with cross-section $A$ at speed $v$ exerts a force $F$ on a wall (at 90 degrees), acc.:

$$F=\rho Av^2$$

With $\rho$ the density of the water.

But your specification of *"8" pipe with 500psi stream of water exiting it and hitting a wall at 90 degrees 8 feet away"* does not allow to compute a value for $v$. So the problem is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Actually. the velocity can be determined as follows.

V = sq. root of 2gh where: V = velocity in ft./sec. g = acceleration const. 32.2 ft per sec per sec. And h = head in feet of liquid.

h = P * 2.31/SG where: P = pressure in psi. SG = liquid specific gravity.

With the above information you can now calculate F.